# Feature engineering for verb\non-verb classification

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, naive-bayes, feature-engineering

Suppose we have data of X = words, and for each word we have a label indicating whether the word is a verb or a non-verb. So, y = labels.

Assuming we can build all the unigrams and bigrams of each of the words and put them in datasets 1-grams and 2-grams respectively.

Any ideas for features that would you choose in order to classify each word to verb or non-verb with NB, logistic regression?

Currently the features I've selected are:
1. Is the word starts\end with the 1-gram\2-gram?
2. How many times the 1-gram\2-gram appears in the word.

And it seems that those features are not producing good results on test-set.

Comment: What language? One suggestion is to add information about context, i.e. other words before and after the one you make predictions for.

Comment: The language is English. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it would be a good suggestion if my data X includes sentences. but in my case I don't have any. I only have data of words without any context.

Comment: If you don't have context, then you don't.